# datatables inline editing

Tags: jquery, datatables

How to use inline editing for multiple tables on a single page ? I am generating tables with a loop and each table has different id and same class. When i bind datatable and makeEditable function with class of table ,I get inline editing with only first table .If I use tables ids in for each loop with jquery ,it gives me a warning. How to solve this?

Comment: Please provide some actual code we can look at.